# Get data out MySQL is very slow

Tags: python, mysql

I need to get some data from MySQL workbench into Python so I can make graphs. 
But when I try to insert it and try to print the values, this is with pymysql (see code). It runs very slow.

So I think when I'm doing live graphs and more stuff the program will freeze...

Does someone have a solution?

My code:

```
import pymysql

conn= pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                      port= 3306,
                      user= 'root',
                      passwd= '******',
                      db= 'energie'
                      )
a = conn.cursor()

sql1 = 'SELECT `VarValue`, `VarName` from `gasmeter1`;'
a.execute(sql1)

gasmeter1 = a.fetchone()

sql2 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `gasmeter2`;'
a.execute(sql2)

gasmeter2 = a.fetchone()

sql3 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `gasmeter349`;'
a.execute(sql3)

gasmeter349 = a.fetchone()

sql4 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `binnentemp ahu3010`;'
a.execute(sql4)

Binnentemperatuur = a.fetchone()

sql5 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `buiten temp241`;'
a.execute(sql5)

Buitentemperatuur = a.fetchone()

print (gasmeter1[0] , gasmeter2[0] , gasmeter349[0] , Buitentemperatuur[0] , Binnentemperatuur[0])
```

It is just a simple code but it is very slow. Someone suggestions?

Time:

code:

```
import pymysql
import time

conn= pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                    port= 3306,
                    user= 'root',
                    passwd= 'ohdecg',
                    db= 'energie'
                     )

a = conn.cursor()

t1 = time.time()

sql1 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `gasmeter1`;'
a.execute(sql1)

gasmeter1 = a.fetchone ()

sql2 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `gasmeter2`;'
a.execute(sql2)

gasmeter2 = a.fetchone ()

sql3 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `gasmeter349`;'
a.execute(sql3)

gasmeter349 = a.fetchone ()

sql4 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `binnentemp ahu3010`;'
a.execute(sql4)

Binnentemperatuur = a.fetchone()

sql5 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `buiten temp241`;'
a.execute(sql5)

Buitentemperatuur = a.fetchone()

t2 = time.time()
print("The SQL statement took : {} s".format(t2 - t1))
#print (gasmeter1[0] , gasmeter2[0], gasmeter349[0])

>>> 
========================= RESTART: C:\Python27\j.py =========================
The SQL statement took : 32.0269999504 s
>>>
```

Comment: This needs more context and better phrasing. "Insert" in the relational database world means a different thing... So your question is confusing. 
Also, you might wanna try appending `LIMIT 1` to your queries instead of using `fetchone`

Comment: And what exactly means "very slow" in your context. (the expected and the observed speed)

Comment: Can I use LIMIT 1 in Python?

Comment: I want graph with the data from MySQL and I inserted the time so updated on the second.. But when I plot graphs with the data the time is stuck for a 10 seconds

Comment: Maybe i can use 2 different programs for this

Answer (score 0):

How big are your tables? You're retrieving the entire table each time and then just take the first element. You could try and time them with something like this:

```
import time
...

t1 = time.time()
sql4 = 'SELECT `VarValue` from `binnentemp ahu3010`;'
a.execute(sql4)
t2 = time.time()
print("The SQL statement took : {} s".format(t2 - t1))
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with the DB-connection. Either that's slow or you're retrieving a lot of data. You could time the statements individually to see which ones are slow. Also, check how big those tables are to see if that may be the issue. You could try limiting the scope of your queries with a 'where' clause.

Comment: I have tried fetchone instead of fetchall, so I read just 1 value and it 's running slow to.. So it's nothing with the amount of data

Comment: sql3: 5 seconds, sql4: 7 seconds, sql5: 7 seconds and sql1 and 2 are under 1 second